# Install mysql-client inside a zip

Tags: python, mysql, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

What I am trying to do is use `aws-lambda` to import zipped sql files in `aws-rds`. In my case zipped sql files are inserted in `s3` constantly by some crawlers. What I want to do is when any sql file is uploaded to an s3 bucket, I want `aws-lambda` to use a `mysql-client` to import these files into `aws-rds`.

They way I have think of doing this is by packaging a mysql-client inside the zip for the `aws-lambda` `handler`. But I can't really figure out how to package mysql inside a zip. Is this possible? If yes, then a list of steps to achieve this would be really helpful!

PS: I am using python-2.7 for writing the `aws-lambda` `handler`. I am not interested in using any `python-mysql` library to achieve this task. The reason being, I don't want to unzip the files and load them in memory and than execute them. These files can be very large, so I don't want to load them in memory.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, using a python mysql library would not in any sense require you to load the entire file into memory. Unzip into a pipe or fifo and read one line at a time and send it to the server as a query... exactly the same way the MySQL CLI would do it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for the hep mate! I didn't know something like that way possible. But I wanted to write as little code as possible. Anyways I managed to package a generic linux compatible mysql executable in the zip! It was way easier than I thought it was :P